# How to use Google Maps to determine the distance between two places?

Tags: google-maps

I want to use data from [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) in my application.

I have two text boxes to add destination A and destination B respectively and I have a panel where I want to show exact mileage or distance of the destination A from destination B using the same data that appears on the Google Maps web GUI, pictured below.

How can I achieve this?

[image]populated on my web-page

Comment: which Google Maps API do you want to use ? There are quite a few API in the Google Maps API family.

Comment: Which platform, language & frameworks are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just directing your users to the Google Maps web site, then note that the URL you've linked to already accepts the source and destination addresses as parameters.

For example, to link to the directions between Delhi and Mumbai:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=delhi&daddr=mumbai

---

**EDIT:** Now that you've been clearer about what you want to achieve, it's clear that you'll need to use one of the [Google Maps API family](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html). Specifically, I suggest that you look at the [Distance Matrix](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) in the [Web Services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) API. It sounds like exactly what you're looking for:

> The Google Distance Matrix API is a service that provides travel
>   distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The
>   information returned is based on the recommended route between start
>   and end points, as calculated by the Google Maps API, and consists of
>   rows containing duration and distance values for each pair.

Comment: As per my requirement I have two textboxes to Add destination A and destination B respectively and I have panel where I want to show exact mileage or distance of the destination A from destination B

Comment: You might want to update your question to say that, rather than say "This URL has two textboxes in Get Direction option, I want to fill these input boxes from my application..."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - Requirement is I have two textboxes to Add destination A and destination B respectively and I have panel where I want to show exact mileage or distance of the destination A from destination B Thanks in Advance for all sort of help

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect this extra info, and added a comment to the question with a request for further info.